# Google Analytics real time not showing in Shopping Behaviour

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I'm using Google Tag Manager to pull data from the Data Layer on an e-commerce site to Google Analytics, but I'm getting a few errors that I cannot fix nor find suggestions online for (I've been searching all week so far).

The process should pick up *sessions with product views* and *sessions with add to cart*, but neither of these seem to be working; both in real time events and in shopping behavior.

Attached are screenshots of the Google Tag Manager with the two tags firing as they should with no errors, what is showing in real time at the time of firing, the shopping behavior page, and the Data Layer for the product I was looking at.

I noticed while editing the Data Layer image that the code in question **does not** have red quotation marks like *gtm.dom* does.  Would this affect it at all?

All code is in JavaScript on PHP pages.  I have done this before for getting the checkout data which is working fine.  I followed the same steps on Simos blog but I am getting these issues now.
Images in order are:

- Data layer
- Real time results
- Shopping behaviour
- Tag manager

[image: Data Layer]

[image: Real time results]

[image: Shopping behavior]

[image: Tag manager]

Any assistance with this is greatly appreciated and please let me know if you need further information or screenshots/code examples.

Many thanks

Comment: There are strange spaces, the name is that? What is actually sent to Analytics? Can you show it by debugging? Then, the price should be a number, without valute symbol.

Comment: My best guess is that you dont have an event action. Can you click onto the tag itself and show them?

Comment: Screenshots are - https://imgur.com/a/13PxzKp (Add to cart event) and https://imgur.com/a/OVZQwr6 (Product View event)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly which of these would be the key reason, but observations:

1) Your add to cart event is a click events instead of Custom Events. Update your trigger type from Click - All Elements to Other - Custom Event, and use AddToCart as the event.

2) You are sending a string value (product name) as the event value. This should be a numeric value.

3) Price should not have a currency symbol in front of it, it should just be a number.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, sdhaus.  I tried these and no change unfortunately, AddToCart is still not showing in the shopping behavior.  

What do you mean by sending a string value in product name?  Is this not correct?  
Also, the price doesn't have a currency symbol - it returns either GBP or EUR depending on the users language setting. 

I've managed to work out the ProductView by changing the trigger, but doing the same to the AddToCart trigger does nothing.

Comment: @Aaron What do you mean by sending a string value in product name?  - No, you should not be sending characters as a value. Value should be a number. The price doesn't have a currency symbol - The price does have a dollar value in your screenshot of the dataLayer. Can you screenshot your updated add to cart event?

Comment: Apologies I misread your reply.  I thought you meant the currencyCode variable, not the prix variable.  I've amended this now and still not getting anything through.  Updated event is here - https://imgur.com/a/rPfIwqI (I've renamed it to AddToBasket for continuity and to avoid conflict with other code)

Comment: Yeah, click on Trigger type. Change to Custom Event, and make the Custom Event name AddToCart

Comment: Gave this a go, custom event doesn't seem to work.  Not firing at all with a custom event.

Comment: Given your dataLayer structure it is a custom event. Can you send screenshots of AddToCar event, and the tag and trigger conditions and why it is not firing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207379/discussion-between-sdhaus-and-aaron).